# Extract insert statements from a previous made back-up with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a file with .backup extension but I need to get only the Insert Statements from this previously made back-up, the problem is that for some reason I can't restore this back-up anymore due to encoding errors, so my question is:

with this file .backup can I extract the insert statements without having to restore the entire database then making a pg_dump again?

Comment: Extensions are only advisory/conventions.  What format is the backup in?  E.g. what argument for -F was given to pg_dump.

Comment: It has a .backup extension. I am not sure how the back-up was made since it was made by another team.

Comment: Take a look inside it with `less` or something.  Does it appear to be binary or text?